# SSRS 2008 Toggle and Hide

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an rs report that has a lot of fields in for various codes and it has several groups. I've set the groups on a toggle so that you can expand the group to see all the subgroups, however what i'd like to do is hide any of the sub groups that have 0 value. I set the visiblity to be based on an expression and toggle on the set field but it doesn't work.

Am i missing something or does RS not support this? The code i am using to set the hide is `=IIF(Fields!VALUE.Value= 0, True, False)` and toggle set to to Col1.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Also, do the subgroups have multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the subgroup if the subgroup has no values?  If there are multiple rows in the subgroup, I think the expression you used will only check the Fields!VALUE.Value for the first row in that group.

Try =IIF( SUM( IIF( IsNothing(Fields!VALUE.Value), 0, Fields!VALUE.Value) )=0, True, False ) instead.

Is Col1 a textbox within the group you are setting the Hidden property for?  It needs to be in a parent group.